# Change CSS drop down menu in a drop up menu

Tags: css, menu

I'm almost certain this question has been answered in one form or another. Applying the changes I've found here and elsewhere doesn't seem to get me any further.

I'm trying to change the css menu from crisislab.nl from a drop-down menu to a drop-up menu. (As you can see on the site I'm currently working on it.)

Current problem I'm encountering is the fact that menu seems to be working fine, expect for the fact that the menu text is displayed downwards and while the menu is moving up (If this doesn't sound logical, please look at crisislab.nl)

See the code below for my current progress. Anyone willing to assist?

Many thanks in advance!

```
                #navigation {
                width: 980px;
                height: 38px;



        }
            #navigation li {
                float: left;
                position: relative;

                               top: 220px;
            } #navigation li:hover { background: transparent  url(gfx/navigation_hover.png) repeat; }
                #navigation li a {
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    color: white;
                    padding: 13px 33px;
                    line-height: 38px;
                    font-size: 11px;
                }
                    #navigation li a:hover { text-decoration: none;}
                    #navigation li ul {

                        position: absolute;
                        background: transparent  url(gfx/navigation_hover.png) left top repeat;
                        z-index: 1000;
                        min-width: 100%;
                                                 display:none; 
                                                left:-1px;
                    }
                    #navigation li:hover ul {


                                                        display:block;   

                    }
                        #navigation li ul li {
                            background: none;
                            width: 100%;
                    }
                            #navigation li ul  li:hover {
                                    background: none;
                                background-color: #2a51b5;



                            }
                            #navigation li ul li a {
                                text-transform: uppercase;
                                color: white;
                                padding-left: 8px 10px;
                                line-height: 28px;
                                width: 100%;
                                display:block;



                            }
```

Comment: Please address a problem you're encountering

Comment: I'll do so when it's fixed. Currently working on it and hopefully done in ten minutes or so.

Comment: and, how far are you with your menu? Can you apply the changes to the example-fiddle please?

Comment: Unfortunately still not there. I've added the changes. This makes the menu move up and the text move down (if you understand what I mean).

Comment: No not really, and if you want to address a comment to me add @Christoph in front of it, else i won't get notified. Have you tried my example fiddle? Can you explain your problem with the help of it?

Answer (score 3):

The basic difference from a dropdown to a dropup is the offset of the child `ul`:

Dropdowns have `top:<x>px;` and if you want a dropup you just say: `bottom:<x>px;`

I modified your code to make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/fJSVz/

Basically i changed the following rules:

```
#navigation li ul {
     top: -9999px;        /* <- removed */
     display:none;        /* <- this will trigger the hide/show */
}
#navigation li:hover ul {
     bottom:20px;         /* <- this is the trick to push the ul up */
     display:block;       /* <- show the ul on hover */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll see if I can fix it. I'm a bit of a novice and basically correcting someone elses mistakes but I should get there :-).

Comment: @NathanQuite Try that out and play around a bit, if you have any further problems - just ask;)

Comment: At this point I seem to be stuck somewhere when trying to apply your changes to the site (see crisislab.nl).

I've been able to put the menu in the right place, but now the text apears to being  going down again instead of up. Any extra help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I've changed the code above to let you know what my last changes are.